# AngularJS - How to show/hide table column on checkbox selection - Generated from nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I have created a Plunker with my code showing the issue [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3G2cQymQ00jPH0P07eCi?p=preview):

As you can see when you click on the e.g. 'de' checkbox it toggles show/hide of the table headings - but not the `<textarea>` values under the column heading, corresponding to the locale ('de' in this case), which is what I am currently trying to get working.

I cant think of a way to link the `<textarea>` depending on `locale.Selected` value of the checkbox. So when `locale.Locale == res.LocaleID` I want to show/hide depending on the `locale.Selected` value.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Resource Id</th>
        <th ng-repeat="locale in view.resourceGridResources.Locales" ng-show="locale.Selected">
            {{locale.Locale ? locale.Locale : "invariant" }}
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="resource in view.resourceGridResources.Resources">
        <td>{{resource.ResourceId}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="res in resource.Resources">
            <textarea ng-model="res.Value"
                      ng-blur="view.saveGridResource(res)"
                      style="min-width: 300px"
                      //trying to get to locale.Selected here - how get index 'x'?
                      ng-show="view.resourceGridResources.Locales[x].Selected">
                      </textarea>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Trying to implment something like [here](http://jsbin.com/zekepiwegu/edit?html,js,output) - whereby user can click on the check box and it will toggle hide/show table column.

Please note: my demo plunker is just example of issue in my much larger project so I have no control over changing the json format etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to write any function in JS. Since the number of items in `resource.Resources` is same as the number of items in `view.resourceGridResources.Locales`.

**HTML**

```
    <td ng-repeat="res in resource.Resources" ng-show="vm.resourceGridResources.Locales[$index].Selected">        
        <textarea ng-model="res.Value"
                  style="min-width: 300px"></textarea>
    </td>
```

**Working Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/Al4KdHlCV2uo9HQ2qNt7?p=preview

Comment: No But the $index of resource.Resources will be in parallel with $index of view.resourceGridResources.Locales?

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to your controller:

```
vm.check = function(res) {
  return vm.resourceGridResources.Locales.find(function(loc) {
    return loc.Locale === res.LocaleId && loc.Selected;
  });
};
```

Add this condition to your view:

```
<td ng-repeat="res in resource.Resources" ng-show="vm.check(res)">
```

A working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/neQtu8qxQQVP2kDIY5ru?p=preview.